# How different is Client Side MVC from Ajax based partial page update?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have very recently started reading in detail about 'Client Side MVC' architecture. During this reading, I was trying to differentiate it from one of my recent Server Side MVC architecture implementation.

Scenario 1: (Server Side MVC Architecture)

> View/Presentation Layer: A Web page created using
>   html/jsp/css/bootstrap + jQuery for Ajax & DOM manipulation. The web
>   page invokes the business functions (in Struts2) via Ajax calls and
>   receives the response in JSON format. It uses jQuery library to
>   perform DOM manipulation and to do partial refresh of the page with
>   the received response/result data.
>
> Controller/Model Layer: The Struts2 class has the controller logic and
>   the business functionality implemented in POJO classes but, returns
>   the results in JSON format.

Scenario 2: (Client Side MVC Architecture)

> View/Presentation Layer: A web page using html/css + libraries like
>   AngularJS.. etc Controller/Model Layer (in Server): Java or PHP or any
>   other server side technology to provide Rest based Service.

In both scenarios listed above, how different is the client side MVC architecture ? It seem to be similar, i.e. having server side business functionality implemented as functions returning result in JSON format (instead of returning html/jsp/view) and the client side code uses the data to update the view.

***Could someone help me understand the difference (if any) between these 2 scenarios (Server and Client side MVC) ?***

Comment: Lemme guess, you managed to find those terms on a side of som framework.

Comment: @tereško we've already built an application as described in scenario 1 .. now when i started reading about client side mvc, i started comparing it with what i already knew and there came these questions..

Comment: Well ... I tend to describe an app as "clientside MVC", when the triade exists completely on the frontent and uses (usually RESTish) backend application as data source. Kinda in the same was as backend apps use database as data source.

Comment: @tereško  Should clientside MVC always rely upon RESTish backend ? in our scenario 1, it wasn't truly RESTish, but it was mere business functions (implemented in POJO classes) callable from frontend and they returned result/data in JSON format

Comment: "Should clientside MVC always rely upon RESTish backend ?" - I think this is the real question.